# Class class = null; Что это значит?

Tags: java, ооп, классы, объекты

Столкнулся в примере с такой записью. Что она значит и для чего ее используют?

В [вики](https://ru.wikipedia.org/wiki/Null_object_(%D1%88%D0%B0%D0%B1%D0%BB%D0%BE%D0%BD_%D0%BF%D1%80%D0%BE%D0%B5%D0%BA%D1%82%D0%B8%D1%80%D0%BE%D0%B2%D0%B0%D0%BD%D0%B8%D1%8F)) нашел, что:

> Целью Null-object является инкапсулирование отсутствия объекта путём замещения его другим объектом, который ничего не делает.
>
> Данный шаблон проектирования рекомендуется использовать, когда:
>
> 1. Объект требует взаимодействия с другими объектами. Null Object не устанавливает нового взаимодействия — он использует уже установленное взаимодействие.
> 2. Требуется абстрагирование «общения» с объектами, имеющими NULL-значение.
> 3. Какие-то из взаимодействующих объектов должны бездействовать.
>    Требуется абстрагирование «общения» с объектами, имеющими NULL-значение.

Что означают второй и третий пункты и где используются?

Comment: У вас есть полный пример листинга?

Comment: @АнтонСорокин расписал в ответе.

Comment: В вики первые два пункта записаны вместе и есть еще третий пункт.

Comment: @defaultlocale исправил

Answer (score 10, accepted):

В общем случае паттерн из вики на который вы ссылаетесь и ваш кусок кода ничего общего не имеют.

```
Class class = null;
```

это просто экземпляр класса которому присвоено `null` (отсутствующее) значение. Это значит что ссылка не указывает ни на какой объект. Попытка вызвать методы объекты приведёт к исключению.

А паттерн как раз создан для того чтобы такие значения исключать. При взаимодействии с NullObject не будет исключения. Это позволяет писать более явный и чистый код без дополнительных проверок объектов на `null`-значения перед использованием.

Comment: метод `forName` исключения не вызовет :)